# An unhandled exception occurred: Project target does not exist

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a problem when I write:

`ionic cordova prepare  android،`

Knowing that this is happening with every new project I create.
Please help.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do as it says, check the `errors.log` file  and post it here as **text**

Answer (score 10):

The problem is caused by required builders that are missing from the `angular.json` file. To install those builders, run:

```
ng add @ionic/cordova-builders
```

You should get an output similar to this:

[image]

After that, go ahead and run your build.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic CLI v6.19.0 has been released with this fix:

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli@latest
```

bug report on GitHub:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/24940#issuecomment-1068016921

[image]